# linux date, CPU usage and memory script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, memory

I am a beginner at scripting but I’m trying to make a shell script called monitornsusystem.sh that will append system related information to the file: systemstatus.log. This system information I need to append is: current date and time, CPU utilization as a percentage and system memory in use as a percentage. I can get all the right information from individual commands but when I put them together in a script, it’s not working the way I planned.

```
#!/bin/bash
sysstat=echo “date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' | echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}’)]% | free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}’” >> systemstatus.log
```

Comment: In what way is it not 'working as planned'? I see a couple of potential issues with the command you posted, but it would be useful to know specifics.

Comment: Those `“` characters look a bit like double-quotes `"`, but they are different.  That really won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I just can figure out that your desired command and output could be:

```
echo -n $(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')" " && echo -n $(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $15}')" " && echo $(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
```

Which would provide:

```
27/02/2017 12:40:47 99 78.2968
```